# Insert PDF file into Latex only with a text box

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm inserting a pdf file into my latex file in Overleaf, but it only gives a empty box with no image,

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
\caption{model framework}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I don't know what's wrong over there, and I checked the file name is correct
and I already have such related packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question so we can check if you have the draft option enabled. Please also check your overleaf project settings that you don't have "compile fast" selected.

Comment: You might want to try [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)

Comment: Is the pdf file in the same parent folder as your main tex file on Overleaf? Of course the name and extension must be correctly spelled but also the path must fit...